# Adding automatically/manually sections to package documentation

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I have build my package and used `devtools::build_manual()` to build package documentation. The problem is that I have all my functions in section 'R topics documented' and I don't know how to change that. My goal is to have several sections without it that 'R topics documented'. I'm not sure how to do that, I tried to do `@describeIn` and `@section` but both didn't work. Do you have any idea how can I do that ?

**UPGRADE vol 1** (After Abdessabour's code)

Hi I want to tell how much I appreciate your work, I know that you for sure spend  a lot of time doing that. I get intuition of your code, it's brilliant. I have two questions about your code which I do not get in 100%.

(1) where in your code can I define section I want to have ? I understand intuition behind **how** they are being made but not quite understand **where** exactly in a code is place to made them. So for example functions (1) and (2) in section A functions (3) and (4) in section B and so on.

(2) How can I create a pdf after running your code. Should I just run `devtools::build_manual()` and that's all ?

**UPGRADE vol 2**

Hi! I understand your way of thinking but I have one problem which I want to show you. Let's say my package has name 'visualise'. That's the files within 'visualise' package folder.

[image]

visualise.R contains my functions within sections. I put that file into package folder (as you can see above)

[image]

I tried to import that file into R by `@import`, `@importClassesFrom`, `@importFrom`, `@importMethodFrom` but all of them don't work. I think R may do not recognize that file. I have concerns because after that creation visualise.R file I run `build_manual(toc="anything")` and in output I get default documentation (same one as created by `build_manual()`) Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

**UPGRADE VOL 3**

I've put visualise.R in R_HOME folder and in R_HOME/bin and it didn't work for both options. I put content of R_HOME/bin/Rd2pdf code below :

```
tex.mod <- function(pkg='.', file='Rd2.tex',  tocTi = "R{} topics documented:"){
  
  library(stringr)
  #get the package name
  pkg <- devtools::as.package(pkg)$package
  #reads the latex file
  out <- readLines(file)
  # modifies the Table of contents title
  out[rdcont] <- sub("(?<=\\\\Rdcontents\\{).+(?=}$)", tocTi, out[rdcont <- grep('\\\\Rdcontents', out)], perl=T)
  # Gets the defined sections
  sections <- str_replace_all(strcapture(paste0("(?s)^.+?\\\\HeaderA\\{",pkg,"\\}.+?(\\\\begin\\{Section\\}.+\\\\end{Section})\n\\\\inputencoding\\{.+$"), paste0(out, collapse='\n'), data.frame(v=character(0)), perl=T)[1,1],  c('\\\\begin\\{Section\\}\\{(.+?) *\\}\n'='\\1\n', '^\n'='', '\n$'='', '\n%?\n'='\n'))
  # splits sections
  spl <- str_split(sections, '\n?\\\\end.+?(\n|$)')[[1]]
  spl <- str_split(spl[nchar(spl)>0], '\n')
  
  #gets the package description
  pkgdesc <- out[1:rdcont]
  # gets the trailing lines
  trailing <- out[length(out)+(-1:0)]
  # get the descriptions
  outi<- str_split(paste0(out[(rdcont+2):(length(out)-2)], collapse='\n'), '\\\\inputencoding.+\n')[[1]]
  # sets the names to th name of the function/package described
  names(outi) <- str_extract(outi, '(?<=\\\\HeaderA\\{).+?(?=\\})')
  # adds lines to add to the toc file if you want more indentation put section instead of chapter
  outi <- c(outi, sapply(spl, function(x) {v<-paste0("\\myaddcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\\protect\\textbf{", x[1],"}}"); names(v)<-x[1]; v})) 
  # unlists the names of the sections with their functions
  spl <- unlist(spl)
  # orders them so that the functions that have no section are shown first
  outi <- c(pkgdesc, outi[!(names(outi) %in% spl)], outi[spl], trailing)
  # writes to file
  if (require(data.table)){
    # the data.table way
    fwrite(list( outi), quote=F, sep='\n', file=file, append=F)
  } else {
    # the baseR way
    fileConn<-file(file, open='w')
    writeLines(outi, fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
  }
  
}
..Rd2pdf <- function (args = NULL, quit = TRUE) 
{
    do_cleanup <- function() {
        if (clean) {
            setwd(startdir)
            unlink(build_dir, recursive = TRUE)
        }
        else {
            cat("You may want to clean up by 'rm -Rf ", build_dir, 
                "'\n", sep = "")
        }
    }
    Usage <- function() {
        cat("Usage: R CMD Rd2pdf [options] files", "", "Generate PDF output from the Rd sources specified by files, by", 
            "either giving the paths to the files, or the path to a directory with", 
            "the sources of a package, or an installed package.", 
            "", "Unless specified via option '--output', the basename of the output file", 
            "equals the basename of argument 'files' if this specifies a package", 
            "or a single file, and 'Rd2' otherwise.", "", "The Rd sources are assumed to be ASCII unless they contain \\encoding", 
            "declarations (which take priority) or --encoding is supplied or if using", 
            "package sources, if the package DESCRIPTION file has an Encoding field.", 
            "The output encoding defaults to the package encoding then to 'UTF-8'.", 
            "", "Files are listed in the order given: for a package they are in alphabetic", 
            "order of the \\name sections.", "", "Options:", 
            "  -h, --help\t\tprint short help message and exit", 
            "  -v, --version\t\tprint version info and exit", 
            "      --batch\t\tno interaction", "      --no-clean\tdo not remove created temporary files", 
            "      --no-preview\tdo not preview generated PDF file", 
            "      --encoding=enc    use 'enc' as the default input encoding", 
            "      --outputEncoding=outenc", "                        use 'outenc' as the default output encoding", 
            "      --os=NAME\t\tuse OS subdir 'NAME' (unix or windows)", 
            "      --OS=NAME\t\tthe same as '--os'", "  -o, --output=FILE\twrite output to FILE", 
            "      --force\t\toverwrite output file if it exists", 
            "      --title=NAME\tuse NAME as the title of the document", 
            "      --toc=NAME   use NAME as the title of the Table of contents", 
            "      --no-index\tdo not index output", "      --no-description\tdo not typeset the description of a package", 
            "      --internals\ttypeset 'internal' documentation (usually skipped)", 
            "      --build_dir=DIR\tuse DIR as the working directory", 
            "      --RdMacros=pkglist", "             \t\tpackages from which to get Rd macros", 
            "", "The output papersize is set by the environment variable R_PAPERSIZE.", 
            "The PDF previewer is set by the environment variable R_PDFVIEWER.", 
            "", "Report bugs at <https://bugs.R-project.org>.", 
            sep = "\n")
    }
    options(showErrorCalls = FALSE, warn = 1)
    if (is.null(args)) {
        args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
        args <- paste(args, collapse = " ")
        args <- strsplit(args, "nextArg", fixed = TRUE)[[1L]][-1L]
    }
    startdir <- getwd()
    if (is.null(startdir)) 
        stop("current working directory cannot be ascertained")
    build_dir <- paste0(".Rd2pdf", Sys.getpid())
    title <- ""
    tocTi <- ""
    batch <- FALSE
    clean <- TRUE
    only_meta <- FALSE
    out_ext <- "pdf"
    output <- ""
    enc <- "unknown"
    outenc <- "latin1"
    index <- TRUE
    description <- TRUE
    internals <- FALSE
    files <- character()
    dir <- ""
    force <- FALSE
    pkglist <- NULL
    WINDOWS <- .Platform$OS.type == "windows"
    preview <- Sys.getenv("R_PDFVIEWER", if (WINDOWS) 
        "open"
    else "false")
    OSdir <- if (WINDOWS) 
        "windows"
    else "unix"
    while (length(args)) {
        a <- args[1L]
        if (a %in% c("-h", "--help")) {
            Usage()
            q("no", runLast = FALSE)
        }
        else if (a %in% c("-v", "--version")) {
            cat("Rd2pdf: ", R.version[["major"]], ".", R.version[["minor"]], 
                " (r", R.version[["svn rev"]], ")\n", sep = "")
            cat("", "Copyright (C) 2000-2011 The R Core Team.", 
                "This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2", 
                "or later for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty.", 
                sep = "\n")
            q("no", runLast = FALSE)
        }
        else if (a == "--batch") {
            batch <- TRUE
        }
        else if (a == "--no-clean") {
            clean <- FALSE
        }
        else if (a == "--no-preview") {
            preview <- "false"
        }
        else if (a == "--pdf") {
        }
        else if (substr(a, 1, 8) == "--title=") {
            title <- substr(a, 9, 1000)
        }
        else if (substr(a, 1, 6) == "--toc=") {
            tocTi <- sub("--toc=", "", a)
        }
        else if (a == "-o") {
            if (length(args) >= 2L) {
                output <- args[2L]
                args <- args[-1L]
            }
            else stop("-o option without value", call. = FALSE)
        }
        else if (substr(a, 1, 9) == "--output=") {
            output <- substr(a, 10, 1000)
        }
        else if (a == "--force") {
            force <- TRUE
        }
        else if (a == "--only-meta") {
            only_meta <- TRUE
        }
        else if (substr(a, 1, 5) %in% c("--os=", "--OS=")) {
            OSdir <- substr(a, 6, 1000)
        }
        else if (substr(a, 1, 11) == "--encoding=") {
            enc <- substr(a, 12, 1000)
        }
        else if (substr(a, 1, 17) == "--outputEncoding=") {
            outenc <- substr(a, 18, 1000)
        }
        else if (substr(a, 1, 12) == "--build-dir=") {
            build_dir <- substr(a, 13, 1000)
        }
        else if (a == "--no-index") {
            index <- FALSE
        }
        else if (a == "--no-description") {
            description <- FALSE
        }
        else if (a == "--internals") {
            internals <- TRUE
        }
        else if (substr(a, 1, 11) == "--RdMacros=") {
            pkglist <- substr(a, 12, 1000)
        }
        else if (startsWith(a, "-")) {
            message("Warning: unknown option ", sQuote(a))
        }
        else files <- c(files, a)
        args <- args[-1L]
    }
    if (!length(files)) {
        message("no inputs")
        q("no", status = 1L, runLast = FALSE)
    }
    if (WINDOWS) 
        files[1L] <- sub("[\\/]$", "", files[1L])
    if (dir.exists(files[1L])) {
        if (file.exists(file.path(files[1L], "DESCRIPTION"))) {
            cat("Hmm ... looks like a package\n")
            dir <- files[1L]
            if (!nzchar(output)) 
                output <- paste(basename(dir), out_ext, sep = ".")
        }
        else if (file.exists(f <- file.path(files[1L], "DESCRIPTION.in")) && 
            any(grepl("^Priority: *base", readLines(f)))) {
            cat("Hmm ... looks like a package from the R distribution\n")
            dir <- files[1L]
            if (!nzchar(output)) 
                output <- paste(basename(dir), out_ext, sep = ".")
            if (index && basename(dir) == "base") {
                index <- FALSE
                cat("_not_ indexing 'base' package\n")
            }
        }
        else {
            dir <- if (dir.exists(d <- file.path(files[1L], "man"))) 
                d
            else files[1L]
        }
    }
    else {
        if (length(files) == 1L && !nzchar(output)) 
            output <- paste(sub("[.][Rr]d$", "", basename(files)), 
                out_ext, sep = ".")
    }
    if (!nzchar(dir)) 
        dir <- paste(files, collapse = " ")
    if (dir.exists(build_dir) && unlink(build_dir, recursive = TRUE)) {
        cat("cannot write to build dir\n")
        q("no", status = 2L, runLast = FALSE)
    }
    dir.create(build_dir, FALSE)
    if (!nzchar(output)) 
        output <- paste0("Rd2.", out_ext)
    if (file.exists(output) && !force) {
        cat("file", sQuote(output), "exists; please remove it first\n")
        q("no", status = 1L, runLast = FALSE)
    }
    res <- try(tools:::.Rd2pdf(files[1L], file.path(build_dir, "Rd2.tex"), 
        title, batch, description, only_meta, enc, outenc, dir, 
        OSdir, internals, index, pkglist))
    if (inherits(res, "try-error")) 
        q("no", status = 11L, runLast = FALSE)
    if (!batch) 
        cat("Creating", out_ext, "output from LaTeX ...\n")
    setwd(build_dir)
    tocTi <- if(nchar(tocTi)>0) tocTi else "\\R{} topics documented:"
    tex.mod(pkg=files[1L], file="Rd2.tex", tocTi=tocTi)
    res <- try(tools:::texi2pdf("Rd2.tex", quiet = FALSE, index = index))
    if (inherits(res, "try-error")) {
        res <- try(tools:::texi2pdf("Rd2.tex", quiet = FALSE, index = index))
        if (inherits(res, "try-error")) {
            message("Error in running tools::tools:::texi2pdf()")
            do_cleanup()
            q("no", status = 1L, runLast = FALSE)
        }
    }
    setwd(startdir)
    cat("Saving output to", sQuote(output), "...\n")
    file.copy(file.path(build_dir, paste0("Rd2.", out_ext)), 
        output, overwrite = force)
    cat("Done\n")
    do_cleanup()
    if (preview != "false") 
        system(paste(preview, output))
    if (quit) 
        q("no", runLast = FALSE)
}
..Rd2pdf()
```

**UPGRADE vol 4**

I'm using code following :

```
# modifies the latex of the converted .Rd files
# in order to add sections to the toc
tex.mod <- function(pkg='.', file='Rd2.tex',  tocTi = "R{} topics documented:"){
  
  library(stringr)
  #get the package name
  pkg <- devtools::as.package(pkg)$package
  #reads the latex file
  out <- readLines(file)
  # modifies the Table of contents title
  out[rdcont] <- sub("(?<=\\\\Rdcontents\\{).+(?=}$)", tocTi, out[rdcont <- grep('\\\\Rdcontents', out)], perl=T)
  # Gets the defined sections
  sections <- str_replace_all(strcapture(paste0("(?s)^.+?\\\\HeaderA\\{",pkg,"\\}.+?(\\\\begin\\{Section\\}.+\\\\end{Section})\n(?:\\\\inputencoding\\{|\n?\\\\printindex).+$"), paste0(out, collapse='\n'), data.frame(v=character(0)), perl=T)[1,1],  c('\\\\begin\\{Section\\}\\{(.+?) *\\}\n'='\\1\n', '^\n'='', '\n$'='', '\n%?\n'='\n'))
  
  # splits sections
  spl <- str_split(sections, '\n?\\\\end.+?(\n|$)')[[1]]
  spl <- str_split(spl[nchar(spl)>0], '\n')
  
  #gets the package description
  pkgdesc <- out[1:rdcont]
  # gets the trailing lines
  trailing <- out[length(out)+(-1:0)]
  # get the descriptions
  outi<- str_split(paste0(out[(rdcont+2):(length(out)-2)], collapse='\n'), '\\\\inputencoding.+\n')[[1]]
  # sets the names to th name of the function/package described
  names(outi) <- str_extract(outi, '(?<=\\\\HeaderA\\{).+?(?=\\})')
  # adds lines to add to the toc file if you want more indentation put section instead of chapter
  outi <- c(outi, sapply(spl, function(x) {v <- paste0("\\chapter{", x[1],"}", '\n', "\\myaddcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\\protect\\textbf{", x[1],"}}"); names(v)<-x[1]; v})) 
  # unlists the names of the sections with their functions
  spl <- unlist(spl)
  # orders them so that the functions that have no section are shown first
  outi <- c(pkgdesc, "\\renewcommand\\thesection{}", outi[!(names(outi) %in% c(spl, pkg))], outi[spl], trailing)
  # writes to file
  if (require(data.table)){
    # the data.table way
    fwrite(list( outi), quote=F, sep='\n', file=file, append=F)
  } else {
    # the baseR way
    fileConn<-file(file, open='w')
    writeLines(outi, fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
  }
  
}

write.fun <- function(fun, path){
  fun.src <- capture.output(fun)
  fun.name <- as.character(substitute(fun))
  fun.src[1] <- paste0(fun.name[length(fun.name)],' <- ', fun.src[1])
  fun.src<-fun.src[!grepl('^<.+?>$',fun.src)]
  if (require(data.table)){
    # the data.table way
    fwrite(list(fun.src), quote=F, sep='\n', file=path, append=T)
  } else {
    # the baseR way
    fileConn<-file(path, open='a')
    writeLines(fun.src, fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
  }
}
# get the location of R_HOME
Rh <- Sys.getenv('R_HOME')
f <- file.path(Rh, 'bin', 'Rd2pdf.overload.R')
file.create(f)

# adds the function to the file
write.fun(tex.mod,f)
write.fun(tools:::..Rd2pdf,f)

# reads the file
out <- readLines(f)
# forces all functions to be loaded from tools
out <- gsub('(?=(.DESCRIPTION_to_latex|.Rdfiles2tex|latex_canonical_encoding|texi2pdf|.Rd2pdf)\\()', "tools:::", out, perl=T)
# add param description to usage
out[i] <- paste(out[i <- grep('--title=NAME', out, fixed=T)], '            "      --toc=NAME\tuse NAME as the title of the Table of contents", ', sep='\n' )
# parses param
out[grep('substr(a, 1, 8) == "--title="', out, fixed=T)+2] <- paste('        }', '        else if (substr(a, 1, 6) == "--toc=") {', '            tocTi <- sub("--toc=", "", a)', '        }', sep='\n')
# adds definition
out[grep('    title <- ""', out, fixed=T)] <- '    title <- ""\n    tocTi <- ""'
# adds call to tex.mod to force modification
out[i] <- paste0(out[i<-grep('setwd\\(build_dir\\)', out)], '\n\ttocTi <- if(nchar(tocTi)>0) tocTi else "\\\\R{} topics documented:"\n\ttex.mod(pkg=files[1L], file="Rd2.tex", tocTi=tocTi)')
# adds call to ..Rd2pdf at the end
out <- c(out, '..Rd2pdf()')
# rewrites the file
fileConn<-file(f, open='w')
writeLines(out, fileConn)
close(fileConn)

# overloading devtools::build_manual
build_manual <- function (pkg = ".", path = NULL, toc=NULL) 
{
  pkg <- devtools::as.package(pkg)
  path <- rlang::`%||%`(path, dirname(pkg$path))
  
  name <- paste0(pkg$package, "_", pkg$version, ".pdf", collapse = " ")
  tryCatch(msg <- callr::rscript(file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "bin", "Rd2pdf.overload.R"), cmdargs = paste0('nextArg', paste0(c("--force", 
                                                                                                                                   paste0("--output=", path, "/", name), pkg$path, if(!is.null(toc)) paste0("--toc=",toc)), collapse='nextArg')), fail_on_status = TRUE), 
           error = function(e) {
             cat(e$stderr)
             stop("Failed to build manual", call. = FALSE)
           })
  cat(msg$stdout)
  invisible(msg)
}


write.fun(build_manual, file.path(path.expand('~'), '.Rprofile'))

build_manual(toc="Functions")
```

with output :

[image]

As you can see "Section one" and "Section two" is mentioned two times, embolden and not embolden. How can I have only embolden one ?

Comment: is this the result you [want](https://i.imgur.com/rpJNqDx.png)? I found a workaround to achieve this

Comment: are u on linux, macos or windows? so I could write a script that'll make the changes

Comment: I am a windows user

Comment: Yea, that's quite interesting result. If it could be done also to .Rd files it would be wonderful.

Comment: well the workaround only works for the first title. :(

Comment: I guess this is the result you [want](https://i.imgur.com/STgcIAi.png). I'm trying to bundle the code into a function and overload `devtool::build_manual` function

Comment: This is exactly the result I'm looking for!

Comment: I updated my answer as the older one was for another question and added the code that made that output. if you need detailed explanations just comment

Comment: I updated my answer by two questions. Many thanks to you one more time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written an `Rscript` that'll take care of all the edits to be made.

## Explanation of the solution

Basically the `devtools::build_manual` calls the `R CMD Rd2pdf` script and this script basically bundles the args to call `tools:::..Rd2pdf`.

So what I did was overload the `tools:::..Rd2pdf` function and add a `--toc` param to change the toc title, and add another function `tex.mod` that'll modify the latex before it's rendered these two function are saved to `${R_HOME}/bin/Rd2pdf.overload.R` so they could be used by the modified `Rd2pdf`, modify the `Rd2pdf` script basically execute `Rd2pdf.overload.R` instead of running `tools:::Rd2pdf()` and overload the `devtools::build_manual` to accept a `toc` param that'll be passed to the `Rd2pdf` script.

`tex.mod` reorders the descriptions and adds the sections to the toc using `myaddcontentsline` macro defined in the `Rd` latex package which is a wrapper to the latex macro `addcontentsline`.

Note: the functions that are not contained in the sections are shown first.

## How sections will be defined

Section will be defined by documenting the [package](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-packages).
ie create an R file with the name `ur.pkg.name.R` and add the description of the package like this:

```
#' name.of.ur.pkg : A package for doing awesome things.
#'
#' The name.of.ur.pkg package provides two categories of important functions:
#' foo and baz.
#' 
#' @section Foo functions:
#' first.fun
#' second.fun
#' 
#' @section baz functions:
#' third.fun
#' fourth.fun
#' 
#' @docType package
#' @name name.of.ur.pkg
NULL
```

## the Rscript:

```
# modifies the latex of the converted .Rd files
# in order to add sections to the toc
tex.mod <- function(pkg='.', file='Rd2.tex',  tocTi = "R{} topics documented:"){
    
    library(stringr)
    #get the package name
    pkg <- devtools::as.package(pkg)$package
    #reads the latex file
    out <- readLines(file)
    # modifies the Table of contents title
    out[rdcont] <- sub("(?<=\\\\Rdcontents\\{).+(?=}$)", tocTi, out[rdcont <- grep('\\\\Rdcontents', out)], perl=T)
    # Gets the defined sections
    sections <- str_replace_all(strcapture(paste0("(?s)^.+?\\\\HeaderA\\{",pkg,"\\}.+?(\\\\begin\\{Section\\}.+\\\\end{Section})\n(?:\\\\inputencoding\\{|\n?\\\\printindex).+$"), paste0(out, collapse='\n'), data.frame(v=character(0)), perl=T)[1,1],  c('\\\\begin\\{Section\\}\\{(.+?) *\\}\n'='\\1\n', '^\n'='', '\n$'='', '\n%?\n'='\n'))
    
    # splits sections
    spl <- str_split(sections, '\n?\\\\end.+?(\n|$)')[[1]]
    spl <- str_split(spl[nchar(spl)>0], '\n')
    
    #gets the package description
    pkgdesc <- out[1:rdcont]
    # gets the trailing lines
    trailing <- out[length(out)+(-1:0)]
    # get the descriptions
    outi<- str_split(paste0(out[(rdcont+2):(length(out)-2)], collapse='\n'), '\\\\inputencoding.+\n')[[1]]
    # sets the names to th name of the function/package described
    names(outi) <- str_extract(outi, '(?<=\\\\HeaderA\\{).+?(?=\\})')
    # adds lines to add to the toc file if you want more indentation put section instead of chapter
    outi <- c(outi, sapply(spl, function(x) {v<-paste0("\\myaddcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\\protect\\textbf{", x[1],"}}"); names(v)<-x[1]; v})) 
    # unlists the names of the sections with their functions
    spl <- unlist(spl)
    # orders them so that the functions that have no section are shown first
    outi <- c(pkgdesc, outi[!(names(outi) %in% c(spl, pkg))], outi[spl], trailing)
    # writes to file
    if (require(data.table)){
        # the data.table way
        fwrite(list( outi), quote=F, sep='\n', file=file, append=F)
    } else {
        # the baseR way
        fileConn<-file(file, open='w')
        writeLines(outi, fileConn)
        close(fileConn)
    }
    
}

write.fun <- function(fun, path){
    fun.src <- capture.output(fun)
    fun.name <- as.character(substitute(fun))
    fun.src[1] <- paste0(fun.name[length(fun.name)],' <- ', fun.src[1])
    fun.src<-fun.src[!grepl('^<.+?>$',fun.src)]
    if (require(data.table)){
        # the data.table way
        fwrite(list(fun.src), quote=F, sep='\n', file=path, append=T)
    } else {
        # the baseR way
        fileConn<-file(path, open='a')
        writeLines(fun.src, fileConn)
        close(fileConn)
    }
}
# get the location of R_HOME
Rh <- Sys.getenv('R_HOME')
f <- file.path(Rh, 'bin', 'Rd2pdf.overload.R')
file.create(f)

# adds the function to the file
write.fun(tex.mod,f)
write.fun(tools:::..Rd2pdf,f)

# reads the file
out <- readLines(f)
# forces all functions to be loaded from tools
out <- gsub('(?=(.DESCRIPTION_to_latex|.Rdfiles2tex|latex_canonical_encoding|texi2pdf|.Rd2pdf)\\()', "tools:::", out, perl=T)
# add param description to usage
out[i] <- paste(out[i <- grep('--title=NAME', out, fixed=T)], '            "      --toc=NAME\tuse NAME as the title of the Table of contents", ', sep='\n' )
# parses param
out[grep('substr(a, 1, 8) == "--title="', out, fixed=T)+2] <- paste('        }', '        else if (substr(a, 1, 6) == "--toc=") {', '            tocTi <- sub("--toc=", "", a)', '        }', sep='\n')
# adds definition
out[grep('    title <- ""', out, fixed=T)] <- '    title <- ""\n    tocTi <- ""'
# adds call to tex.mod to force modification
out[i] <- paste0(out[i<-grep('setwd\\(build_dir\\)', out)], '\n\ttocTi <- if(nchar(tocTi)>0) tocTi else "\\\\R{} topics documented:"\n\ttex.mod(pkg=files[1L], file="Rd2.tex", tocTi=tocTi)')
# adds call to ..Rd2pdf at the end
out <- c(out, '..Rd2pdf()')
# rewrites the file
fileConn<-file(f, open='w')
writeLines(out, fileConn)
close(fileConn)

# overloading devtools::build_manual
build_manual <- function (pkg = ".", path = NULL, toc=NULL) 
{
    pkg <- devtools::as.package(pkg)
    path <- rlang::`%||%`(path, dirname(pkg$path))

    name <- paste0(pkg$package, "_", pkg$version, ".pdf", collapse = " ")
    tryCatch(msg <- callr::rscript(file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "bin", "Rd2pdf.overload.R"), cmdargs = paste0('nextArg', paste0(c("--force", 
        paste0("--output=", path, "/", name), pkg$path, if(!is.null(toc)) paste0("--toc=",toc)), collapse='nextArg')), fail_on_status = TRUE), 
        error = function(e) {
            cat(e$stderr)
            stop("Failed to build manual", call. = FALSE)
        })
    cat(msg$stdout)
    invisible(msg)
}


write.fun(build_manual, file.path(path.expand('~'), '.Rprofile'))
```

It automatically adds the new definition of build_manual to `~/.Rprofile`.

After running `devtools::document()` you can

- Now to build your manual run `build_manual()`
- Now to build your manual with a custom Table of contents title pass a toc argument to the call

Comment: As far as I gather it converts r markdown files. Is there any possibility that it will automatically do same thing with my .Rd files ?

Comment: @John hopefully this answers your questions

Comment: Hey, I've updated my question. I'm pretty close to the answer but not sure what doing wrong.

Comment: @John you need to put visualize.R in the `R` folder and then run `devtools::document()`, can you please post the contents of `${R_HOME}/bin/Rd2pdf`

Comment: I post that in my question ;))

Comment: @John I meant the `Rd2pdf` script not `Rd2pdf.overload.R`

Comment: This is Rd2pdf file opened by R, Look up to my question, I've added a screen

Comment: Ok add the following to your question after running it in R `cat(readLines(file.path(Sys.getenv('R_HOME'), 'bin', 'Rd2pdf')), sep='\n')`. I think this will show the source of the problem

Comment: Done! I added this into my question

Comment: the problem is that the `Rd2pdf` script does not exist in windows that's why it doesn't get modified and it has the same contents as `Rd2pdf.overload.R`. I'll try to locate it in order to solve this.

Comment: Oh.. I see the problem. Thank's for your help!

Comment: @John I have found a solution I basically dropped the call to the `Rd2pdf` script and now call `Rd2pdf.overload.R` directly. all you need to do is copy the `build_manual`to your `.Rprofile`

Comment: Great! I have just one question because it's very strange. I already have build_manual in my profile so I'm not sure what should I add

Comment: @John I modified the code in my answer replace the one in `.Rprofile`

Comment: Hey, It's working! I've just added to my question one little thing about reading visualise.R. I'm not sure what can I do more to make my R read it

Comment: @john put the `visualise.R` in the `package_folder/R` then run `devtools::document` then call `build_anything`

Comment: I've done those steps and still I have output. I see "anything" instead of "R topics documented" but I do not have any sections within table of contents

Comment: (Same as in the last image in my question)

Comment: what are the contents of the `package_folder/man` folder

Comment: II should work as the visualize.Rd has been created

Comment: the problem is that your `package.name` is the last in the alphabetic order that's why the regex fails to match it. Tonight I'm going to edit this in order for it to work.

Comment: @John now remove the `build_manual` from your `.Rprofile` and copy the new `Rscript` and rerun it

Comment: Thank you very much mate! Now it's working in 100%. I just have one little question. Is there possibility to do not include visualise.Rd in table of contens ? I mean to do it only for modifying without inclusion. (Now I have all functions in table of contents but i do also have visualise.R)

Comment: @John copy the new `tex.mod` to `Rd2pdf.overload.R`

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you very much!!!!!! Really!!!

I'm just wondering if there is any simple way how to include that Section 1 and Section 2 in documentation. I mean now we have included section 1 and section 2 only in table of contents and there is no strict border within documentation between them.

Comment: @John replace  `outi <- c(outi, sapply(spl, function(x) {v<-paste0("\\myaddcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\\protect\\textbf{", x[1],"}}"); names(v)<-x[1]; v}))` with `outi <- c(outi, sapply(spl, function(x) {v<-paste0("\\chapter{", x[1],"}"); names(v)<-x[1]; v}))`

Comment: change chapter to section if the Section title looks too big

Comment: Okey! Section instead of chapter is perfect! Is there any way to delete that 0.1, 0.2 and so on values, which precedes section titles ? ;))

Comment: i.e. to just have Section one, Section two in documentation instead of 0.1 Section one, 0.2 Section two

Comment: change `outi <- c(pkgdesc,......` to `outi <- c(pkgdesc, "\\renewcommand\\thesection{}"`

Comment: Hmmm, I've changed   `outi <- c(pkgdesc, outi[!(names(outi) %in% c(spl, pkg))], outi[spl], trailing)` to `outi <- c(pkgdesc, "\\renewcommand\\thesection{})"` and get `Loading required package: data.table
Warning in system(paste(shQuote(texi2dvi), if (quiet) "--quiet" else "",  :
  running command '"C:\Users\t654118\AppData\Local\MICROS~2\AppV\Client\INTEGR~1\8290A4~1\Root\miktex\bin\texi2dvi.exe"  --pdf "Rd2.tex" --max-iterations=20 -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1`
Error : running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' fail

Comment: @john it should look like this `outi <- c(pkgdesc, "\\renewcommand\\thesection{}", ....)`

Comment: It's working! I see now only "Section 1" and "Section 2" within documentation. But now I do not see Section1 and Section2 bolded in table of contents. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @John ok replace `v<-paste0("\\chapter{", x[1],"}")`  with `v <- paste0("\\chapter{", x[1],"}", '\n', "\\myaddcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\\protect\\textbf{", x[1],"}}")`

Comment: Yea! And the very last thing! Now I have both : embolden Section 1 in table of contents and not embolden. How can I delete not embolden one ? i.e. In table of contents I want to have only "Section 1" mentioned one time embolden.

Comment: I don't understand the problem @John. can you upload an image to imgur

Comment: I've added that to my question ;))

Comment: @John sorry for the late answer I have exams these weeks. the fix for this is easy all you need to do is change `"\\chapter{"` to `\\chapter*{` this creates an unnumbered which is by default not included in the Table of contents